# How do you switch a yml between release and prerelease

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

A company I work for has recently switched to using YAML for their pipelines.  They trigger on master branch, and they version "byBuildNumber".  However, we are finding it difficult to determine the process to build a specific branch into a prerelease.

I imagine the ability to change the `versioningScheme` based on master versus Anything Else?  I know you can use "byPrereleaseNumber", but we don't want ALL builds to be prereleases, so just sticking that in there doesn't seem to be the answer.

Maybe altering or dynamically-altering the yaml isn't the answer I'm looking for.  But the basic question is; in Azure DevOps, how do you run your build configuration, but with a prerelease NuGet pack?

I'm hoping the only answer isn't to create two completely different pipelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if totally get your point. It's able to use **multiple stage** YAML pipeline to creates a prerelease version of the NuGet package and a release version of the NuGet package.

Then you can specify the **conditions** under **which each stage runs**. By default, a stage runs if it does not depend on any other stage, or if all of the stages that it depends on have completed and succeeded. You can customize this behavior by forcing a stage to run even if a previous stage fails or by specifying a custom condition.

With this option, you could manually choose to build and publishes the prerelease package or release package or both package to private Azure DevOps Artifacts feeds.

For step by step tutorial, please take a look at  [Using multi-stage YAML pipeline to create and publish NuGet packages](https://ronaldbosma.github.io/blog/2019/09/03/using-multi-stage-yaml-pipeline-to-create-and-publish-nuget-packages/)